# How do I make water as seen in Sea Stars?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, chipmunk

There is a nice Sea Stars iOS application out there, with a good looking water effect can be seen on [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooU6cTeirlQ).

I have found Tiny Wings "waves" tutorial on [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1), so I guess I can figure out how to make waves.

I wonder how do I make effect when hero pops out of the water (splash and water deformation). Also I wonder how do I make effect when I look on water line from above and from below - please notice how water line changes when hero is above it and below it.

I am familiar with Box2d and Cocos2d, so I wonder if this can be done within that knowledge. Also I wonder if Chipmunk can help.

Comment: I guess they are using some soft body physics engine.. and soft body physics is not supported by Box2d.. but I am not quite sure.. I am also looking for almost same thing from weeks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the waves in sea stars aren't really simulated, but just simple perlin noise and adding a simple bump when making a splash. If you want water simulation, I posted some code I wrote to do that here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/25494